# Заливка текста svg выходит за границы символа

Tags: html, svg

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема (или я что-то не понимаю). Есть SVG

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   height="100%"
   style="background:#FFFFFF"
   version="1.1"
   viewBox="0 0 1024 1024"
   width="100%"
   id="svg59"
   sodipodi:docname="Auto.svg"
   inkscape:version="0.92.2 (5c3e80d, 2017-08-06)">
  <metadata
     id="metadata63">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <defs id="defs32">
    <style type="text/css" id="style9">
    .default_default {
      fill: #808080;
      stroke: #000000;
      stroke-width: 0.5px;
    }
</style>
    <filter height="1" id="filter.808080" width="1" x="0" y="0">
      <feFlood flood-color="#808080"/>
      <feComposite
         in="SourceGraphic"/>
    </filter>
    <filter height="1" id="filter.FF00FF" width="1" x="0" y="0">
      <feFlood flood-color="#FF00FF"/>
      <feComposite in="SourceGraphic"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <g id="root" transform="translate(0,0)">
    <text id="c9_5_1_text_0" transform="translate(576,384)" fill="#000000" font-family="Times New Roman" font-size="22pt" filter="url(#filter.808080)">
      <tspan x="0" dy="0em" id="tspan52">Test</tspan>
    </text>
    <text id="c5_3_1_text_0" transform="translate(320,256)" fill="#000000" font-family="Times New Roman" font-size="36pt" filter="url(#filter.FF00FF)">
      <tspan x="0" dy="0em" id="tspan55">0</tspan>
    </text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Текст отображается так, если открыть в редакторе:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добавляю svg на страничку:

```html
<iframe frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" src="Auto.svg" id="AutoId"></iframe>
```

При загрузке страницы, `filter` заливает текст не по границам,а больше (сверху и снизу заметно):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Весьма странный у вас способ добавления svg. Каким боком тут вообще iframe ?

Comment: @Hikikomori, object не получалось нормально масштабировать.

Comment: А подключение через img чем вас не устраивает ?

Comment: @Hikikomori, мне нужно управлять svg через js - трансформация, анимация и т.п. => нужен объект, а не картинка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Причина в параметрах фильтра**

Область видимости действия фильтра на объект называется - [Filter effects region](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/filters.html#FilterEffectsRegion)

Это прямоугольник, с габаритными размерами `width="X%"`, `height="Y%"` заданными в определении фильтра   `filter  id="filter.808080">`

Также могут быть заданы координаты левого верхнего угла `региона действия фильтра` - `x="X%"` `y="Y%"`

Если эти все параметры не указаны, то они будут по умолчанию равны:

`x="-10%"`, `y="-10%"` `width="120%"` `height="120%"`

Поэтому у вас подложка была шире символа `svg`

Укажите  значения этих параметров, чтобы обеспечить необходимый внешний вид цветной подложки:

Я выбрал следующие значения, вы можете перенастроить их по своему вкусу:

```
<filter  id="filter.808080"  x="10%" y="10%"  height="75%" width="90%">
```

Ваш пример ниже.

Файл я прогнал через [svg оптимизатор](https://petercollingridge.appspot.com/svg-editor), чтобы убрать ненужную служебную информацию `Inkscape`

```html
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="100%" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 1024 1024" width="100%"  background="#FFFFFF">
        <defs>
    <style type="text/css" id="style9">
      
    .default_default {
      fill: #808080;
      stroke: #000000;
      stroke-width: 0.5px;
    }

    </style>
      <filter  id="filter.FF00FF"  x="10%" y="12%"  height="70%" width="90%">
      <feFlood flood-color="#FF00FF"/>
      <feComposite in="SourceGraphic"/>
    </filter>
  
  <filter  id="filter.808080"  x="10%" y="10%"  height="75%" width="90%">
      <feFlood flood-color="#808080"/>
      <feComposite in="SourceGraphic"/>
    </filter>
  
  </defs>
  <g id="root" transform="translate(0,0)">
    <text id="c9_5_1_text_0" transform="translate(576,384)" fill="#000000" font-family="Times New Roman" font-size="22pt" filter="url(#filter.808080)">
      <tspan x="0" dy="0em" id="tspan52">
        Test
      </tspan>
    </text>
    <text id="c5_3_1_text_0" transform="translate(320,256)" fill="#000000" font-family="Times New Roman" font-size="36pt" filter="url(#filter.FF00FF)">
      <tspan x="0" dy="0em" id="tspan55">
        0
      </tspan>
    </text>
  </g>
</svg>
```